# Photoshop, how to save a rectangle I select to PNG without creating a new file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, png

I have a graphics artist deliver a PSD file with a lot of images in one. Each layer is a PSB file. I need to cut rectangular images from the large list and save in PNG format.

Is there a way for me to cut a rectangle out of a very large photoshop file and save it without pasting contents into a new document?

Comment: I used @Tianzhen Lin's solution and it's perfect. If I could upvote I would. I have a large scrolling screenshot for my app. In order to turn that large scroll into 5 iPhone-screen sized samples, I just selected the underlying screen image for each inside the larger scroll, one at a time, and Copy Merged. Then one at a time, I pasted each individual clipboard into a new PSD and BAM! all of the graphics that were contained within each selection box reappeared, appropriately sized for my screenshot to upload to iTunes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way of doing this is by using the crop tool (you can also use the `rectangular marquee tool>image>crop`) then save your image as PNG. Then if you wanna cut the rest of the images, then you're just gonna have to go to your history panel and undo the cropping (this will not undo the saved PNG file) then do the same thing as what you did with the first one. I hope this is what you're trying to achieve!

Answer (score 4):

Besides Cropping and Undo'ing, I have found the following steps are less error-prone:

1. Adjust the layers you need
2. Make a marquee selection
3. Ensure a visible layer is being selected, use Edit -> Copy Merged (Shortcut, Cmd-SHIFT-C, or CTRL-Shift-C)
4. Create a new document (Cmd-N or Ctrl-N), Photoshop will automatically set the document to the size of the selection
5. Paste the image
6. Perform a Save for Web (Cmd-Option-Shift-S or CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-S)

I use the above steps a lot over the past number of years as it involves shortcut keys, hence they speed the workflow up and offer the convenience of speed and precision.  I know creating a new doc may not be what you wanted, but the approach may actually end up saving you some time.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. In combination with [saving selections as alpha channels](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-selections-alpha-channel-masks.html), this lets you save any number of different crops that you can re-use at any time.

Answer (score 2):

All i have to do is clicking on the layer and press <kbd>F12</kbd> ;)

You will ask how is that possible. Actions friend..
Here is a nice article on that.

http://viget.com/inspire/single-click-layer-exporting-in-photoshop

Best of luck !

Answer (score 1):

Use the Slice tool, and save the images as slices.

[Photoshop / Slicing web pages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7570a.html)

Basically you slice all the small images, then you can save all of them with one command.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an action like this and assign it to a key combination (in my case Ctrl-F2):

[image: Export Selection action]

Here's an export of the action (for Photoshop CC 2017, not sure if it will work in other versions): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6g334g1yug9gk67/Export%20Selection.atn

Answer (score 0):

I suggest combining Muhammed Aslam C's answer with Tianzhen Lin's...

So use the Action recording to do what Tianzhen Lin describes with the "dialogue on/off" switch on for the save stage.

Saved me a lot of time!